# Can't see the tile for my Windows 8 Store App after deploying through Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

I am developing a Windows 8 Store app. Till sometime back I could see the Tile of the app once I built and ran the Solution from Visual Studio.

However, very recently Visual Studio 2012 seems to have stopped creating the Tile to launch my application in the dev environment. I have to use Application Search to bring up the App shortcut and launch (outside the debugger).

Only recent change in my environment is the Update 1 installation.

Why has Visual Studio stopped creating the Tile or did I mess something up?

Environment:

Windows 8 Pro (x64) 
Visual Studio Express 2012 Update 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have un-pinned it from your start screen, it will be in your All Apps, you need to re-pin it. Most likely you just un-pinned rather than un-install.

Answer (score 0):

Same here but I press **Uninstall** on my app.
Result :

1. My app is missing from "All apps".
2. App also cannot create any new/second icons/tiles.
3. Any new metro app have same problems

I manage to fix it by deleing folder(s) in (this is not good solution. must be another way to restore App):
"C:\Users\UserNameHere\AppData\Local\Packages\"

Comment: You found anything for this?